# Gray bars on bottom and right side while using graphics

Tags: java, graphics, draw

On every game that I make using the usual graphics, I end up getting gray bars on the right side and bottom of my window.

You can see for yourself here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtxR6.png

Any help is appreciated!

### EDIT

**`main(String args[])` method**

```
    Main component = new Main();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(component);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle(name);
    component.start();
```

**render method**

```
    public void render() {
    Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();
    // Drawings
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, screenPixel.width, screenPixel.height);
    level.render(g);
    for(Entity e:Entity.entities){
        e.render(g);
    }

    g = getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 0, 0, screenPixel.width, screenPixel.height, null);
    g.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code.it's look like your jframe

Comment: You definitely should provide some more information to work on.

Comment: @user3555001 try `frame.setContentPane(component);`

Comment: @user3555001 yes comment your add line add that code

Comment: @FastSnail still has the bars :(

Comment: @user3555001 could you post your all codes somewhere like patebin.

Comment: @FastSnail It wouldnt be anywhere else other than those two methods though, and my game is a good 2k lines of code

Comment: @user3555001 what is screenPixel?

Comment: Call `setResizable` before `pack`, call pack just before `setVisible` and AFTER you've established the UI.  Use actual know values for the width and height (`getWidth` and `getHeight`) not `screenSize.width` or `screenSize.height`

Comment: @FastSnail it is the dimensions of the screen, its the exact same as screenSize

Answer (score 0):

Answered by MadProgrammer:

Call setResizable before pack, call pack just before setVisible and AFTER you've established the UI. Use actual know values for the width and height (getWidth and getHeight) not screenSize.width or screenSize.height